# Adapting google map to container div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to insert a map `iframe` inside a `div` and I want it to adapt to the container mantaining its proportions. I have thought of setting the `iframe`'s `width` to `100%` and `height` to `auto` but it doesn't work, a grey block is shown instead of the map. http://jsfiddle.net/3R24j/9/

The map is only shown if `width` **or** `height` have fixed or relative values or both of them, never works with `auto`.  http://jsfiddle.net/3R24j/8/

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Google Maps. It isn't rendered when either the height or width is less than 200px.

You can set your `iframe`'s height to 100% as well, but the `div` container has to be at least  `200x200` for the map to show up.

Comment: My container is 380px x 1143px, it should work according to what you're saying.

Comment: Are these dimensions explicitly set though? If not, then it will be based on its content. If you don't want to set an explicit width and height for your container, at least use `min-width` and `min-height` and set it to 200px. Have the iframe's width and height be 100% as well.